# Make Html form dissepear after submit

Tags: php, html, post

How can i make the Html form dissepear after submit and it will display button to make the form reappear again and clear the result?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
    echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name.";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note : wrapped html in `else` condition

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
    echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name.";
}
else{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
   <input type="text" name="name"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
</form>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: Please check this code, it work as per your requirement

Comment: thanks anyway to make them reappear again?

Comment: Redirect the page to same url, may be using `header("location:your url.php");`

Comment: or just give a link or use javascript to redirect

Comment: Basically load the page again it will re appear

Comment: can we do like this? echo "<center><form><input type="button" value="Home" onClick="window.location.href='http://site.com/'"></form></center>";

Comment: Just give a link like this : `echo "<a href='your_page.php'> Return</a>";`

Comment: thanks how to do that with button?

Comment: Better you give style to anchor tag and make it look like a button

Comment: In stack we say thanks by accepting the answer(click on the tick mark near answer) :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to just insert your whole `form` inside `else` part

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "User Has submitted the form and entered this name : <b> $name </b>";
    echo "<br>You can use the following form again to enter a new name.";
    echo "<a href='your_page.php'> Page</a>";
} else {
?>
 <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
 </form>
<?ph } ?>
```

Comment: thanks anyway to make them reappear again?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').style.display='none'"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: But action is in same page, so it will re appear again after it submits

Comment: Ah, shame on me. I didn't get the whole picture.